# Basic guidance require for MVVM design pattern

Tags: c#, mvvm

i am not familiar with MVVM design pattern. so reading article on it from a url `http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-mango-getting-started-with-mvvm-in-10-minutes`

here is a small code of MVVM design pattern

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;
    private int age;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return this.age;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.age != value)
            {
                this.age = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Age");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

1) i like to know what is the use of `PropertyChangedEventHandler` ??
what it does?

2) i like to know what is `this.RaisePropertyChanged("Age");` is doing ?

please explain it in easy way so i can understand their use and importance.

thanks

Comment: Topic itself can be useful to many people, I'm sure, but I'm also sure it will attract a lot of "not so useful" answers that will not add any value (to what you may find on MSDN/on-line tutorials). I'm still thinking if finally it's on-topic or not...

Comment: You need basic guidance with the event pattern, it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) What is the use of PropertyChangedEventHandler ?? what it does?

[PropertyChangedEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "represents the method that will handle the PropertyChanged event raised when a property is changed on a component." That line of code declares an event called PropertyChanged. Other objects can subscribe to that event to be notified when a property has changed.

2) What is this.RaisePropertyChanged("Age"); is doing ?

this.RaisePropertyChanged("Age") is a call to the RaisePropertyChanged method, which in turn verifies that there are subscribers to the event (handler != null) and if so then notifying them of the change (handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))).

In short it is a pub/sub notification system for one object publishing to it's subscribers that something has changed.

Answer (score 1):

These two things allow your `Person` class to inform the user interface (i.e. the View in MVVM) that something has changed.

So:

`PropertyChanged` is an Event (of type `PropertyChangedEventHandler`) that the View can subscribe to and when triggered might do "something".

`RaisePropertyChanged` is a method that you call within the class to say "Hey, I have changed and fire the event (as mentioned above) please".

So, say your person's name changes then the `PropertyChanged` event will be raised and the View will then be notified that something has happened that it might be interested in. The whole point is the class needs some way to tell the rest of the world that something has happened. It does this by Events. Of course, everyone might ignore that event, but by raising it you have done your part.